# Existence of a Connectivity Polynomial for a simple graph?

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials, random-graphs

I try to find a polynomial for an arbitrary simple graph $G$ that tells whether the graph is connected or not. A graph is **st-connected** if you can find a path between a vertex $s$ and a vertex $t$ -- an example pair is sink and source.

A special case of this are vertex-induced subgraphs of $G$ and edge-induced subgraphs of $G$: suppose I know that $G$ is st-connected, is $G-v$ st-connected after a vertex deletion? Is $G\backslash e$ st-connected after an edge deletion?

*Random graph models*

1. Given a graph $G$, a *vertex-induced random subgraph of $G$* is a new graph by vertex deletions and deletions of its incident edges with some probability $p$ on each vertex where vertices are independently deleted. *What is the connectivity polynomial in the vertex probability?*
2. Given a graph $G$, a *edge-induced random subgraph of $G$* is a new graph by edge deletions and deletions of isolated vertices with some probability $p$ on each edge where edges are independently deleted. *What is the connectivity polynomial in the edge probability?*

I am trying to understand the connectivity of the random graph models with  Percolation theory [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243967/st-connectivity-of-a-finite-graph-with-percolation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853336/probability-for-connection-of-lhs-rhs-in-path-of-bond-percolation).

**Does there exist a polynomial for the connectivity of a simple graph?**

> 1. Given two vertices $s$ and $t$ and a graph $G$, which polynomial tells whether a path exist between $s$ and $t$ in $G$?
> 2. What is the connectivity polynomial for vertex-induced random subgraph?
> 3. What is the connectivity polynomial for the edge-induced random subgraphs?

Comment: Please, provide more attempt of yours. It is now difficult to get into your situation.

Comment: The problem you link to makes me think you are interested in a random graph based on a given graph and want a polynomial in the edge probability.  You need to expand your question to be self-contained; otherwise nobody will know what you are asking.

Comment: You must study the Laplacian polynomial of graphs. The roots of this polynomial gives you the total number of component of an arbitrary graphs.

Comment: Look up "reliability polynomial".

Answer (score 2):

An answer which seems snide (but isn't!) is
$$P(G)=x^k$$ where $k$ is the number of connected components. Another which is possible but maybe not as reasonable is the constant polynomial $Q(G)=k.$

Recall that a **proper** coloring has vertices connected by an edge required to have unequal colors. Define $\chi (G,c)$ to be the number of proper colorings of $G$ with $c$ colors. It turns out this is a polynomial in $c$ which can (perhaps with some effort) be calculated recursively by the relations

- $\chi(s)=x$ for a graph $s$ consisting of a single point
- $\chi(G)=\chi(H)\chi(H')$ if $G$ is the union of disjoint graphs $H,H'$
- $\chi(G)=\chi(G-e)-\chi(G_e)$  Where $G-e$ is $G$ with the edge $e$ removed (but endpoints retained) and $G_e$ is $G$ with the endpoints of $e$ identified (and resulting multiple edges replaced with a single edge.)

Define a **highly improper** coloring to be one where vertices connected by an edge are required to have the same color and let $P(G,c)$ be the number of highly improper colorings with $c$ colors. This turns out to be a polynomial, in fact the one given above. It is no effort to compute but there are relations which are almost the same:

- $P(s)=x$ for a graph $s$ consisting of a single point
- $P(G)=P(H)P(H')$ if $G$ is the union of disjoint graphs $H,H'$
- $P(G)=P(G_e).$

Of course it is also easy to get $Q(G)=k$ with

- $Q(s)=1$ for a graph $s$ consisting of a single point
- $Q(G)=Q(H)+Q(H')$ if $G$ is the union of disjoint graphs $H,H'$
- $P(G)=P(G_e).$